# Changing from FileReader to getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, filereader

[image]When I tried loading my little game from a .jar file the fileReader would no longer work and I was advised to use the getResourceAsStream function instead, when I run the code bellow in the IDE it works fine so the path is correct, when I change to the getResourceAsStream which is currently commented out and remove the file reader line, I get these errors.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
```

Is there a way that I can fix this?

```
public class Utils {
    public static String loadFileAsString(String path) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try{
            //InputStream is = Utils.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
            //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                builder.append(line + "\n");

            br.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/res" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="1.8" jdkType="JavaSDK" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="module-library">
      <library>
        <CLASSES>
          <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/res" />
        </CLASSES>
        <JAVADOC />
        <SOURCES />
      </library>
    </orderEntry>
    <orderEntry type="module-library" exported="">
      <library>
        <CLASSES>
          <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/res/worlds" />
        </CLASSES>
        <JAVADOC />
        <SOURCES />
      </library>
    </orderEntry>
  </component>
</module>
```

Comment: Where is your .jar file located ?

Comment: Ran it on my desktop and in the artifacts folder with same results

Comment: Sorry its meant to be an output stream I think as its reading numbers from a text file, still causes errors though

Comment: I mean, is the JAR in classpath ?

Comment: You probably passed the wrong path. What is the resource you would like to read? Where is it located in your jar file? What path did you use? Have you read the javadoc of Class.getResource[AsStream()] to understand what it does, and what kind of path it expects?

Comment: I am trying to read a .txt file into my program that has numbers in it, the path I am using is "res/worlds/world1.txt", it is located in GameDev/res/worlds/world1.txt. What is re- ?

Comment: I'm using Intellij, the only file I can find with class path information is an .iml file with this info in it.

Comment: Class.getResourceAsStream() uses the classloader to find the resource. So it looks in directories and jars that are in the classpath. The GameDev directory is probably not in the classpath. And even if it was, the path would have to start with a /.

Comment: I have added the class path info to the code above

Comment: I have added a screen shot of my Dependencies which includes all of the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start understanding what you're doing, what the classpath is, how Java loads classes, and how an app is bundled.

When you start a Java program, you use a command looking like this:

```
java -cp /some/directory:/some/file.jar com.foo.bar.Main
```

Given the above command, java will try loading the main class (and all the other classes used in your code) in two locations:

- the `/some/directory` directory
- the jar file `/some/file.jar`

Since the class is named Main, and is in the package com.foo.bar, it will thus look for a file named `/some/directory/com/foo/bar/Main.class` and if it doesn't find it, it will look inside the jar file for an entry `/com/foo/bar/Main.class`.

When you use `SomeClass.getResourceAsStream("/res/worlds/world1.txt")`, it will apply the same strategy: look for a file `/some/directory/res/worlds/world1.txt` and if not found, look inside the jar file for an entry `/res/worlds/world1.txt`.

So, since you use an IDE to run the project, you need to understand how an IDE works: what command does it use to start your program. The principle is quite simple:

- there is a target directory where the IDE puts the .class files it generates from the source .java files. This target directory is part of the classpath when running the program for the IDE
- there is also a target directory where the IDE stores all the files that are not .java files, and are located under a directory in IntelliJ marked as "Resources root". This target directory is also part of the classpath.

The structure in the target directory always respects the structure of the source/resource directory.

When packaging the app as a jar file, you'll end up with a jar file containing everything located under these target directories.

By default, in a basic IntelliJ project, your src directory is also a resources root. So every file you put there ends up in the target directory, and is thus available in the classpath, both when launching from the IDE, and when the target directory is packaged as a jar. You should just put the file somewhere under the src directory, and not mess with dependencies. Your txt file is part of the sources of the project, just like a Java file. It's "compiled" by the IDE by copying it to the directory, along with the .class files.